# Where can I get/generate a custom font?

Tags: creative-writing

One reading *Harry Potter* (and I'm sure they are in other books as well) will notice that J. K. Rowling utilizes several custom fonts, most commonly in letters and handwriting. There is the Hagrid font. There is the Harry Potter font. There's even a font in the fourth book made to look like it is pieces of paper pasted together (Hermione's hate mail).

Where can I generate/order custom fonts like these? Is there a program that can do it?

*For my specific purposes, I am attempting to make a font consisting of Elvish letters.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of research, not about writing.

Comment: I just created a handwritung font using Photoshop (to clean up the scans of the letters), Illustrator (to create clean paths and export as SVGs) and Fontforge (to create the actual font). It was a laborious process. There are also paid services to whom you send a sample of your writing. Google is your friend.

Comment: you might ask at Graphic Design SE.

Comment: @what I did a search for fontforge, but I can't seem to ascertain if it is free or not. Is this the correct program? http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/

Comment: @TommyMyron That's the one. It is free and open source. It is a powerful software but not glitch-free. Also type design and font creation are complex processes so will suck up lots of time. Make sure that is worth it for the maybe three lines of elvish you might easier write by hand and paste into your text as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various online searches that you can perform to learn more information. Here are a couple of general concepts that will help you to determine what you need:

- **Typeface Libraries, or Font Foundries**: These are in the form of either original designers of a family of typefaces, and/or an online store that sells such typefaces (though sometimes free).
- **Typeface design tools**: These are graphic design applications that you can use to either modify an existing typeface, or create a typeface from scratch, and then save the result in a system font file that can then be used by your computer applications.

Being works that involve a creative process, be aware that there are copyright issues with respect to typefaces, with which you must be particularly careful as regards modifying an existing typeface.

With respect to different types of system fonts, there are a handful of systems available, though the more common would be TrueType / OpenType, and Adobe Type 1.

Comment: One more detail. When you have sent your electronic document to a print house, you'll need to send them the font files that are used in the document, otherwise there will be layout issues if a substitute font is used. With respect to copyright, it is considered standard practice to provide the font (either as separate file, or embedded within the document), with the expectation that print house will only use for the purpose of producing the given document.